# Docker port not exposing on localhost

Tags: node.js, docker

I just started using docker on mac and I can't figure out why the ports aren't exposing on localhost.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN apk add --update curl
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY . /home/app
RUN cd /home/app; npm install express
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Here is my sample app:

```
var app = require("express")();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({'lorem': "ipsum"});
});
app.listen(8080);
console.log('listening on 8080');
```

After building, I did docker run:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080  some/test
```

I've checked the docker logs, everything is running fine. I've run docker exec on the container and tried to "curl" the internal port, it's working fine. But I can't open it on localhost.

What is wrong, am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using "Docker for Mac" or "docker-machine" or A N other?

Comment: Docker for mac!

Comment: Have you tried mapping to a different port, like 5000 or so? I get issues sometimes with ports like 80 and 8080.

Comment: I've tried 3000, 5858, 8080, nothing is coming out to localhost. @DriesDeRydt

Comment: It doesn't look like you're missing anything, unfortunately. Can you show us the output of "docker ps" and "docker logs container-id"

Comment: @Rawkode the logs are showing the proper console.log message on the app. docker ps is showing the container running properly. Nothing is broken, the port isn't just coming out to localhost

Comment: have you tried docker attach <containerid> after docker run ...?

Comment: What's the output of `curl localhost:8080` from your mac?

Comment: @Pavel that does just runs the image in attaches mode.

Comment: @Robert the curl was from inside the docker instance, and it's functioning properly. The port is just not being exposed externally.

Comment: Please, tell us what exactly returns running it from your mac (outside the container, your mac console)

Comment: @iKey, yes I'm aware of it, but in this case, you can see if your docker responds to any requests